# c# extract key value pairs from a string

Tags: .net, arrays, regex, replace

i need to parse a longer block of content:

```
content block 1
content block 2 key1="value1" key2="val2" some other content
content block 3 key3="value3" other content
more content
```

I need to get a dictionary or any structure that I can loop through (arrays, collections etc).
So far I was looking at two options: regex or some sort of split into array.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: sorry, the question is how do I extract the pairs (key1,value1), (key2,value2), (key3, value3) ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
string text = @"
        content block 1
        content block 2 key1=""value1"" key2=""val2"" some other content
        content block 3 key3=""value3"" other content
        more content 
    ";
    var pattern = @"(?<key>\w+)\s*=\s*""(?<value>[^""]*)""";
    var matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);

    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (Match match in matches)
        dictionary.Add(match.Groups["key"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value);
```

You might need to fine tune the pattern.  For the key, it is grabbing anything in the set `[A-Za-z0-9_]` that is followed by an `=` sign.

The value is anything that isn't a `"` inside the quotes following the `=` sign.  But if you can have `"`s in your value string, you'll need to adjust for that.

It also allows optional spaces around the `=`, but you can tighten that up if needed.

Comment: that's probably the closest to what I am looking for and it kind of confirms to me that I would have to do it in two steps rather than getting everything in one shot

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
(\w+)="(.+?)"
```

Then iterate over each match and extract `Group[1].Value` (key), `Group[2].Value` (value).